# Nested "from" LINQ query expressed with extension methods

Tags: c#, linq

How can I write this LINQ query by using the extension method syntax?

```
var query = from a in sequenceA
            from b in sequenceB
            select ...;
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For your future reference, all questions of this form are answered by section 7.16 of the C# specification.

Your specific question is answered by this paragraph:

---

A query expression with a second `from` clause followed by a `select` clause

```
from x1 in e1
from x2 in e2
select v
```

is translated into

```
( e1 ) . SelectMany( x1 => e2 , ( x1 , x2 ) => v )
```

---

So your query:

```
var query = from a in sequenceA            
            from b in sequenceB
            select ...;
```

Is the same as

```
var query =  ( sequenceA ) . SelectMany( a => sequenceB , ( a , b ) => ... )
```

(Note that of course this assumes that the "..." is an expression, and not, say, an expression followed by a query continuation.)

hdv's answer points out that

```
var query =  ( sequenceA ) . SelectMany( 
    a => ( sequenceB ) . Select( b => ... ) );
```

would also be a *logically* valid translation, though it is not the translation we actually perform. In the early days of LINQ implementation, this was the translation we chose. However, as you pile on more `from` clauses, it makes the lambdas nest more and more deeply, which then presents the compiler with an *enormous* problem in type inference. This choice of translation wrecks compiler performance, so we introduced the *transparent identifier* mechanism to give us a much cheaper way to represent the seamntics of deeply nested scopes.

If these subjects interest you:

For more thoughts on why deeply nested lambdas present a hard problem for the compiler to solve, see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/26/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-four.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/28/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-five.aspx

For more information about transparent identifiers, see this post from Wes Dyer, who implemented them in C# 3.0:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2006/12/22/transparent-identifiers.aspx

And my series of articles about them:

http://ericlippert.com/2014/07/31/transparent-identifiers-part-one/

Comment: Note that the "C# Language Specification" is a downloadable Word document and is therefore not indexed by most search engines and not readable online. Maybe Microsoft could change that in future!

Answer (score 9):

```
var query = sequenceA.SelectMany(a => sequenceB.Select(b => ...));
```

**Edit**: as pointed out by Eric Lippert in the comments, this gives the same results, but is intentionally not how it is translated internally. See his answer for another way to call `SelectMany`, which does correspond to the original. Also, added the omitted `b =>` for clarity.

Comment: Would a non nested variant like `var query = sequenceA.SelectMany(a => sequenceB).Select(...);` also work?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes That's also possible, but that means you cannot refer to `a` from within the second `Select`'s parameter.

Comment: @hdv: Neither of you are correct. You are right to point out that in Olivier's comment, he has lost the range variable `a`. But in both of your translations you've both lost the range variable `b`. Where did `b` go in your translation? What if `...` refers to `b`? You need another lambda in there somewhere!

Comment: @EricLippert The "b =>" is part of the "..." that needs to be filled in.

Comment: @EricLippert I see in your answer that you write it using another `SelectMany` overload, but as I understand it, it means the same thing as what I answered. I would much appreciate it if you would correct me if that's wrong.

Comment: So what you meant to say was that `from a in sequenceA from b in sequenceB select ...` is *logically* the same as `sequenceA.SelectMany(a=>sequenceB.Select(b=>...))` ? (Note the use of the range variable `b` in the lambda, missing from your answer.) That is correct, yes. We avoid this translation because it leads to deeply nested lambdas, which then produce bad overload resolution performance.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, that is what I meant. I try not to worry about how *exactly* it's internally translated unless I have a good reason. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write it would be:

```
var query = a.Join(b, i => new { }, j => new { }, (i, j) => new { i = i, j = j });
```

Comment: Nested `from`-statements and `SelectMany` both flatten nested enumerations. I.e. they convert an enumeration of enumerations into one flat enumeration containing all the elements of the nested enumerations of the source. They don't join two unrelated enumerations.

Comment: What I did is a cross-join, same as other options which you've listed. The result enumeration is also flat. Go ahead and try it :) .

Comment: Example: Input `string[][] nested = new string[][] {
 new string[] { "a", "b", "c" },
 new string[] { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD" },
 new string[] { "1", "2", "3" },
};`. Expected output: `"a", "b", "c", "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "1", "2", "3"`