# Nice, clean cross join in Linq using only extension methods

Tags: c#, linq, join, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nested “from” LINQ query expressed with extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115675/nested-from-linq-query-expressed-with-extension-methods)

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I honestly couldn't find anything.

I'm curious what the equivalent syntax would be for the following using only built-in Linq extension methods:

```
var z1 =
    from x in xs
    from y in ys
    select new { x, y };
```

I can get the same results with this:

```
var z2 = xs.SelectMany(x => ys.Select(y => new { x, y }));
```

But it produces different IL code, and the code is a bit convoluted and hard to understand. Is there a cleaner way to do this with extension methods?

---

Here's my entire test method as written:

```
private void Test()
{
    var xs = new[] { 1D, 2D, 3D };
    var ys = new[] { 4D, 5D, 6D };

    var z1 =
        from x in xs
        from y in ys
        select new { x, y };

    var z2 = xs.SelectMany(x => ys.Select(y => new { x, y }));
}
```

Here's the [Edit: C# interp of the] IL code (using ILSpy):

```
private void Test()
{
    double[] xs = new double[]
    {
        1.0, 
        2.0, 
        3.0
    };
    double[] ys = new double[]
    {
        4.0, 
        5.0, 
        6.0
    };
    var z =
        from x in xs
        from y in ys
        select new
        {
            x = x,
            y = y
        };
    var z2 = xs.SelectMany((double x) =>
        from y in ys
        select new
        {
            x = x,
            y = y
        });
}
```

Comment: eh, that is not il code?

Comment: That looks like a C# interpretation from disassembly rather than IL.

Comment: Eric Lippert answered pretty much the same question today here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115675/nested-from-linq-query-expressed-with-extension-methods/9117009#9117009

Comment: That looks like consequence of `var`, anonymous delegates and LINQ syntax in C#.

Comment: If the result is the same, why does it matter to you how the disassembler interprets it back into C#?

Comment: You can turn off "View > Options > Decompile query expressions" in ILSpy to see queries in extension method syntax.

Comment: @PauliØsterø, you got me. I guess I pasted in C# interp..still learning how to us ILSpy :)

Comment: @Daniel, great tip, thanks. When I set the options that way, I basically get Magnus's answer. Now I won't need to ask questions like this anymore :)

Comment: @hvd, agreed...voting to close my own question :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

One way would be:

```
var z2 = xs.SelectMany(x => ys, (x, y) => new {x, y});
```

Comment: +1: This is probably the best solution.

Comment: @Magnus, this is it, +1 and thanks. I didn't realize there was an overload of `SelectMany` that let you do that. I have also learned, thanks to @Daniel's comment above, that I can view the extension method version rather than the query syntax in ILSpy, and it came up with basically your answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to use a single LINQ extension method, then another candidate would be [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx), with the `outerKeySelector` and `innerKeySelector` functions defined such that they will always produce equal values.

```
var z3 = xs.Join(ys, x => true, y => true, (x, y) => new { x, y });
```

This will, however, probably give more convoluted IL code than the nested `from` solution. Incidentally, MSDN uses the nested `from` in its example for a cross join; look at the first code snippet in [How to: Perform Custom Join Operations (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882533.aspx).