# is there a c# equivalent of pythons itertools.combinations_with_replacement

Tags: c#, python-itertools

I'm looking to find all the possible ways of rolling 5 six-sided dice. I know in python you can do this using itertools, is there something in c# that can achieve the same?

```
itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r)

for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 6), 5)
```

https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement

The range 1, 6 is number of face on the dice and , 5 is the number of dice being rolled. Want to produce all 7776 ways you can roll the dice. e.g. an initial roll may look like:

Dice 1, Dice 2, Dice 3, Dice 4, Dice 5 = 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Please show your input and expected output - you could also include the relevant python you're trying to reproduce in c#.

Comment: As in you need all possible combinations, or the number of combinations?

Comment: so if I understand right (and my python is not great) `range(1,6)` will give you a set containing `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and the extra parameter passed to `combinations_with_replacement` of `5` says you want all combination sof 5 values - like `12345` and `23456` and `13456` etc? (If im right, there was nothing like that description in your question!!)

Comment: have added this to the question

Comment: Right, so you want all combinations of ways to roll 5 dice -got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy - its basically a [cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120318/nice-clean-cross-join-in-linq-using-only-extension-methods) between a range of 1-6 5 times.

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(1,6);
var result = from d1 in range
                     from d2 in range
                     from d3 in range
                     from d4 in range
                     from d5 in range
            select new { d1,d2,d3,d4,d5 };
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/VKA17045

Comment: this is probably for another question, but this works well for range 1, 6 and 5 dice, but having tried it for some lager numbers the program seems to hang. is there a way to make this scale or do the number of combinations  just get too large?

Comment: @danny possibly too large. What range/combination count are you trying?

Comment: i was trying sides 1, 12 with 20 dice.

Comment: @danny - if 5d6 is expressed as 6^5 combinations (7776), then 20d12 would give 12^20 combinations. That's a VERY big number. You're going to need a supercomputer to work out all combinations.

Comment: 3.8x10^21 combinations to be exact(ish) @danny (or roughly a quarter of the number of atoms in the universe, for comparison)

Answer (score -3):

implementation for what 3615 suggested:

```
Random root = new Random();
List<int> results = new List<int>()
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    results.Add(root.Next(1, 6));
}

//results now contain the 5 dice throws
```

Comment: I dont get how this answers the question. Youre getting a random number between 1-6 5 times and throwing away the result each iteration.

Comment: Honestly, I got a bit lazy with this answer, and you are correct. the answer is thrown away.
Just thought it would give the general direction of what to do.