# C# LINQ to Method syntax

Tags: c#, linq, collections, lambda

Im trying to wrap my head around LINQ statements in C#, Im trying to convert simple queries to the method syntax equivalent.

Most examples i've seen are cluttered with other statements and conditions and use more complex types. For now, i want to keep this as simple as possible.
any tips would be appreciated.

```
// create a list of numbers
List<int> data1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

// create a list of numbers
List<int> data2 = new List<int>() { 5, 6, 7, 8 };  

var query = from n1 in data1
            from n2 in data2
            select n1 * n2;
```

With this, i get 16 numbers that i can iterate over using a foreach loop.
Id like to know how to do the same thing with method syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested "from" LINQ query expressed with extension methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115675/nested-from-linq-query-expressed-with-extension-methods)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The full details are in the C# language specification, section 7.16. Additionally, I have [an article in my Edulinq blog series](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/) which you may find simpler to read.

However, for your particular case... secondary `from` calls always end up being converted to `SelectMany` calls, so you can *start* by thinking of this as:

```
var query = data1.SelectMany(n1 => data2, (n1, n2) => new { n1, n2 })
                 .Select(pair => pair.n1 * pair.n2);
```

But actually the compiler will collapse those two because you've *just* got a `select` clause after the `from`:

```
var query = data1.SelectMany(n1 => data2, (n1, n2) => n1 * n2);
```

It's definitely a good idea to be comfortable with both query expressions and their expansions - I tend to find that when there aren't any transparent identifiers involved (joins, let, etc) then the method syntax is just as easy to read as query expressions, and sometimes simpler - but query expressions simplify things when there are multiple range variables involved.

Comment: I heartily recommend the Edulinq series to anybody who is wanting to understand LINQ better. It is excellently informative at giving you a better understanding of LINQ.

Comment: +1 for nice answer @JonSkeet, I will read more about your `Edulinq` series :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) method:

```
var query = data1.SelectMany(n1 => data2, (n1, n2) => n1 * n2);
```

Comment: Your first example will only result in 4 items, it's not equivalent to the 2nd.

Comment: You are right guys, I will keep only the right solution. :)