# Nested 'froms' in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new in LINQ and I have problem with nested froms:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class MultipleFroms
{
    static void Main()
    {
        char[] chrs = { 'A', 'B', 'C'};
        char[] chrs2 = { 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
        var pairs = from ch1 in chrs
                    from ch2 in chrs2
                    select ch1+" "+ ch2;
        Console.WriteLine("For ABC and XYZ: ");
        foreach (var p in pairs)
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("For D and W: ");
        chrs = new char[] { 'D' };
        chrs2 = new char[] { 'W' };
        foreach (var p in pairs)
            Console.WriteLine(p);
    }
}
```

In output I have:

```
For ABC and XYZ:
A X
A Y
A Z
B X
B Y
B Z
C X
C Y
C Z

For D and W:
A W
B W
C W
```

But I expected:

```
...
For D and W:
D W
```

Why `pairs` in second case used "old" `chrs`, `{ 'A', 'B', 'C'}` instead `{'D'}` ?

Comment: The "var pairs = ...."  is a query when you use the foreach at end of you posted code the query is executed with the new values of chrs and chrs2.

Comment: @jdweng This is wrong,check my answer

Comment: you may have stumbled upon something interesting where even though you didn't re-assign the pairs variable, the next output still used the updated results from one array but not the other. looking into this now.

Answer (score 13):

This question got several good answers which state the obvious - you need to reassign your `pairs` variable. However, I got more interested in the strange behaviour - as, why does reassigning `chrs2` have an effect on the result of the enumeration, and reassigning `chrs` does not.

If we use nested `from`-s, looks like reassigning any of the used collections, *except for the FIRST one*, affects the result of the enumeration: http://ideone.com/X7f3eQ.

Now, as you should probably know, the LINQ "query syntax" is just syntactic sugar for chaining extension method calls from the `System.Linq` library. Let's desugar your specific example:

```
var pairs = from ch1 in chrs
            from ch2 in chrs2
            select ch1 + " "+ ch2;
```

becomes

```
var pairs = chrs.SelectMany(ch1 => chrs2, (ch1, ch2) => ch1 + " " + ch2);
```

(or, with non-extension-method syntaxis, `SelectMany(chrs, ch1 => chrs2, (ch1, ch2) => ch1 + " " + ch2)`)

(check it here: http://ideone.com/NjVeLD)

So, what's going on? `SelectMany` takes `chrs` and two lambdas as parameters, and generates an `IEnumerable` out of them, which can later be enumerated to start the actual evaluation.

Now, whenever we reassign `chrs2`, it changes in the lambda, because it is a captured variable. However, this obviously won't work with `chrs`!

Comment: As I thought : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027811/nested-froms-in-linq/32028782?noredirect=1#comment51959362_32028782

Comment: @lad2025: yes, pretty much, but make sure to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115675/nested-from-linq-query-expressed-with-extension-methods for very relevant discussion!

Comment: @Eser No,this does not seem like the correct explanation

Comment: @GeorgeVovos the keyword here is **captured variable.**

Comment: @Mints97 You said "SelectMany takes chrs and two lambdas as parameters".Select many does not take chrs as a parameter.That's the problem ,it works for chrs2 exactly for the reason you said.chrs2 is a captured variable. Once again,the problem is the the expression before the SelectMany is evaluated when you call SelectMany.It's just difficult to identify the problem because the expression before the SelectMany is just an array so with think that the query will always use the latest values.The problems is clearer if you see the examples in my answer

Comment: @Eser the keyword is **chrs is not a captured variable** ,only chrs2 is. Tha'ts why the unexpected output in the question,the query uses the new values only for the captured variable

Comment: @GeorgeVovos From your answer `This means it will use the contents result of GetChrs() at that time.`No this is not correct, since your example is not correct. Change your method as below and see the result.. **`private static IEnumerable<char> GetChrs()
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetChrs Called");
    yield return 'A';
    yield return 'B';
    yield return 'C';
}`** You won't see the *"GetChrs Called"*

Comment: @L.B What you are saying is correct for my example but does not apply to the original question(But my example demonstrates the problem in the original question ).I hope you understand what I'm saying

Comment: @GeorgeVovos Seems like you **don't** understand what I am saying. Your example doesn't demonstrate anything. `GetChrs().SelectMany(....)`  forces `GetChrs()` to be exceuted and assign the result to a compiler generated value before the rest of IEnumerable be executed. But this is not the OP's case.... *Bad test cases => bad results*

Comment: @L.B That's exactly what **from ch1 in chrs
                    from ch2 in chrs2** does ,it evaluates **ch1** that's why the user get's the wrong output

Comment: @L.B Then explain the output in the original question and this line **char[] expr_68 = new char[]** in my answer

Comment: @GeorgeVovos: you see, `SelectMany` *does* take `chrs` as the first parameter, as an *extension method*. Read up on those =)

Comment: @Mints97 Let me rephrase.It does not capture chrs **That's what matters** ,it only captures chrs2 that's why he gets the strange output

Comment: @GeorgeVovos: isn't that what my answer says? =)

Comment: @Mints97 It seems I misunderstood your answer...I removed my downvote

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to explain this, I can think of, is to note that this

```
var pairs = from ch1 in chrs
    from ch2 in chrs2
    select ch1 + " " + ch2;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var pairs = chrs.SelectMany(ch1 => chrs2, (ch1, ch2) => ch1 + " " + ch2);
```

And that the compiler internally creates a closure class similar to this one:

```
private sealed class Closure
{
    public char[] chrs2;
    internal IEnumerable<char> Method(char ch1)
    {
        return chrs2;
    }
}
```

And then modifies your method to read:

```
static void Main()
{
    Closure closure = new Closure();
    char[] chrs = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
    closure.chrs2 = new[] { 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
    var pairs = chrs.SelectMany(ch1 => closure.chrs2, (ch1, ch2) => ch1 + " " + ch2);
    Console.WriteLine("For ABC and XYZ: ");
    foreach (var p in pairs)
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("For D and W: ");
    chrs = new[] { 'D' };
    closure.chrs2 = new[] { 'W' };
    foreach (var p in pairs)
        Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

I hope that this way it is easy to see how you arrive to your result.
*Note: I made some simplifications during the explanation above to make the poitn stand out better*.

The next question might be "why the compiler is doing this?". The answer is that lambda functions can be passed around and execute in different context to the one they were created it. When that happening it is often desirable to preserve state:

```
public Action<string> PrintCounter()
{
    int counter = 0;
    return prefix => 
        Console.WriteLine(prefix + " " + (counter++).ToString());
}
```

With the example above you can pass the function around as much as you like, yet, the counter is implemented each time you call it. Normally local variables such as `counter` live on stack, so their lifetime is of the function call, the stack is "unwind" when the function finishes execution. To get around this, closures are created, as demonstrated above. Most of the time they are extremely useful because they allow writing code that separates logic/control structures from the details of how they are going to be used. But in some degenerate cases you see the results like the one you've experienced.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look the query as a *method call* where the method receive the first source of data (`chrs`) as parameter. The problem is you can't reassign the object to which you've already called the method after it's been setup. The second source of data (`chrs2`) is like a global variable, that's way when you update its value, the result of the query also changes.

A better approach is move your query to a method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Pairs(char[] chrs,char[] chrs2)
{
      return from ch1 in chrs
             from ch2 in chrs2
             select ch1+" "+ ch2;
}
```

That way you can do something like this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
        char[] chrs = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
        char[] chrs2 = { 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

        Console.WriteLine("For ABC and XYZ: ");
        foreach (var p in Pairs(chrs,chrs2))
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("For D and W: ");
        chrs = new char[] { 'D' };
        chrs2 = new char[] { 'W' };
        foreach (var p in Pairs(chrs, chrs2))
            Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

Comment: So `from ch1 in chrs   from ch2 in chrs2  select ch1+" "+ ch2;` is like `chrs.SelectMany( ch1 => chrs2.Select( ch2 => ch1 + " " + ch2))` and that way chrs cannot reasign?

Comment: Please, I would like to know why are the downvotes. If  someone see that I have something wrong, please, share it to improve my answer

Comment: @lad2025 it can be reassigned all right. It's just independent from what you have in `pairs`. `chrs2` though is a part of `pairs` closure.