# How to convert Linq-to-objects query with two from clauses to method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

How do I convert this LINQ query syntax (this is LINQ to objects) to method syntax:

```
var occupiedSquares = from s in squares
               from p in pieces
               where Occupies(p, s)
               select s;
```

(`Occupies` is a function returning `bool`. But note that a square does not directly hold a list of occupying pieces, nor does a piece directly hold a list of squares it occupies.).

I thought the answer might use`Join`, but I can't seem to make it fit the join syntax, because there isn't a common key. (And does the `Join` method even work on LINQ to objects?).

Comment: What is the `squares` and `pieces`?

Comment: ```squares``` is an ```ImmutableList<Square>```; ```pieces``` is an ```ImmutableList<Piece>```

Comment: The C# specification describes how all queries are transformed into method calls; I suggest you consult it if you are curious about how this works.

Comment: Join does work on LINQ to objects! Both simple joins and join-into clauses are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two consecutive `from`-clauses are translated with a `SelectMany` extension method:

```
var occupiedSquares = squares
    .SelectMany(s => pieces.Select(p => (s, p))) // Creates a ValueTuple
    .Where(x => Occupies(x.p, x.s))
    .Select(x => x.s);
```

If you are working with an older Framework version, you can also use an [Anonymous Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) instead of a [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples).

```
var occupiedSquares = squares
    .SelectMany(s => pieces.Select(p => new { s, p }))
    .Where(x => Occupies(x.p, x.s))
    .Select(x => x.s);
```

Alternatively, you can also apply the Where-clause to the nested `Select`. No aggregate (`ValueTuple` or anonymous type) is required in this case:

```
var occupiedSquares = squares
    .SelectMany(
        s => pieces
            .Where(p => Occupies(p, s))
            .Select(p => s)
    );
```

The [Enumerable.SelectMany Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) is typically used to flatten a nested collection. E.g., you have a list of users and the user objects have a list of posts and you need a list of all the posts.

See also my question [Nested “from” LINQ query expressed with extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9115675/880990) and Eric Lippert's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9117009/880990). (Eric was part of Microsoft's C# compiler team.)